# Objective C moving Labels

Tags: iphone, objective-c, drawing

I am working on a game project, and what i want to do is moving a group of labels in a window, from top of the screen to the bottom, let user read these labels, and fade away (like labels sliding from top to bottom without any trigger).

I thought that a timer variable in a loop would help me slide and change their position according to the timer value.

I made some research but if you share an article with me, i can know what i should look up for.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Chuck is right.  To elaborate:

```
-(void)doTheLabelThing {

    // assume all the labels are in a container view that is 320 wide and 100 tall
    self.labelContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, -100, 320, 100);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        // slide down
        self.labelContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 360, 320, 100);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // give user 3 seconds to read it
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:3.0 options:0 animations:^{
            // fade out
            self.labelContainer.alpha = 0.0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            // restore everything to original state
            self.labelContainer.alpha = 1.0;
            self.labelContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, -100, 320, 100);
        }];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a loop or a timer; use Core Animation. Just do `animateWithDuration:animations:` or similar and set their position to the new place you want them to be.